# Css helper to add to .success,danger,.primary classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple html page that i am creating and in my panels i need the headers to have different colors without hardcoding the colors myself with custom css.

Is there a dropin css file i can have that contains colors that i can use in place of

`.success, .primary, .danger` etc.

To make this even clearer, i want my panel headers and other components that can be styled with

`.success, .primary, .danger` to have other colors.

Has anyone come across such helper?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can customize color of css class.

For each element you can change default colors and download the package with your own graphic elements colors.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize

Answer (score 2):

> To make this even clearer, i want my panel headers and other components that can be styled with .success, .primary, .danger to have other colors.

If you want to style only some specific panel headers inside your site with the mentioned classes you must wrap these inside an outer class like so.

```
<div class="specific-headers">
  <div class="success">
    // ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS file you can override them like this.

```
.specific-headers > .success {
  color: ...,
  background-color: ...
}
```

So you can design your page with the given classes but elsewhere the standard colors are taken.

If you would like all elements with these classes applied to have another color. Just override them directly.

```
.success {
  color: ...,
  background-color: ...
}
```

Be aware of including your own CSS files after the Twitter Bootstrap. Otherwise your customizations will be overwritten.

> I have a simple html page that i am creating and in my panels i need the headers to have different colors without hardcoding the colors myself with custom css.

Why would you not want to hardcode the colors yourself. Somewhere you have to specify your colors. I recommend using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) so you have the benefits of variables to specify your colors.